# Nested loop in common LISP

Tags: common-lisp

I'm trying to created a player that would solve the game Mastermind in LISP. I tried using the following nested loop in a helper function

```
(defparameter *counter* 0) 

;analyze the score to determine whether points need to be added to counter
(defun analyze (last-response)
  (if (> (first last-response) 0)
      (setf *counter* (+ (first last-response) *counter*))))

;helper function for finding correct color
(defun guessColor (length colors last-response)
    (loop while (< *counter* 4) do
       (loop for i from 1 to length
          collect (first colors)
          (setf colors (rest colors)))
    (analyze (last-reponse))))

;baseline Holyguacamole player will guess all colors before trying all combinations of correct color 
(defun HolyGuacamole (board colors SCSA last-response)
  (declare (ignore SCSA))
  ;(print last-response)
  (guessColor board colors last-response)
  (print *counter*)
    ;(sortColor)
)
```

The while loop is supposed to run while the global variable `*counter*` is less than 4. The inside loop is supposed to guess colors based on the length of pegs required (variable length). I've been running into the compilation error

> during macroexpansion of (LOOP WHILE (< *COUNTER* 4) ...). Use ;
>   *BREAK-ON-SIGNALS* to intercept.

I'm unfamiliar with LISP so I'm not sure what that error code means and how to fix it. I felt like I nested it correctly with the proper parenthesis, but I'm not actually sure what's wrong with it.

[Link](http://pastebin.com/8XW8HZza) to Mastermind environment.

Comment: How large is the whole program? Can you paste it or maybe pare it down to a self-contained example? I don't see a definition of `score` or `analyze` or the declaration of `*counter*`

Comment: @GregoryNisbet the code for the game itself is very large. I edited to have my helper functions as well as the declaration of *counter*. score is changed to last-response

Comment: I think `(analyze (last-reponse))))` should be `(analyze last-reponse)))` ... There also seem to be some other errors... I haven't been able to reproduce that exact compiler error with `clisp` or `sbcl`.

Comment: I think even when I had the parenthesis correct for that, my biggest issue is the loops itself.

Comment: You should use the standard naming conventions (`guess-color` instead of `guessColor`) and indent the code a bit better. Currently the `guess-color` function is very hard to read since it looks like the call to `analyze` is outside the loop, while it should be on the same level with the inner loop.

Comment: The error is probably caused by the `(SETF...)` in the inner loop. Only one form is allowed in a `COLLECT`-clause. You probably should put it in a `DO`-clause. Or you could use `POP` insted of `FIRST` and remove the `SETF`. I'm not sure what you expect the inner loop to achieve though. It collects the first `LENGTH` elements from `COLORS`, but its return value is just discarded by the outer loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no obstacle in principle to nesting a loop inside another loop. However, a `COLLECT` or `COLLECTING` clause can only take a single expression, as @jkiiski pointed out.

For instance, the following program

```
(defun nested-loop ()
  (loop for i from 1 to 10 doing
        (loop for j from 1 to 10 collecting
              (print "some string")
              (print (list 'nested-loop i j)))))

(nested-loop)
```

produces a syntax error under CLISP.

```
*** - LOOP: illegal syntax near (PRINT (LIST 'NESTED-LOOP I J)) in
       (LOOP FOR J FROM 1 TO 10 COLLECTING (PRINT "some string")
        (PRINT (LIST 'NESTED-LOOP I J)))
```

Using a `do` or `doing` clause works, as does grouping the multiple expressions associated with a `collecting` clause with `progn`.

```
(defun nested-loop ()
  (loop for i from 1 to 10 doing
        (loop for j from 1 to 10 collecting
              (progn
                (print "some string")
                (print (list 'nested-loop i j))))))

(nested-loop)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Upon further thought, I don't think using nested loop would work the way I want for this game. I've rewritten my code below. It compiles but when testing with print last-response, it's printing all NIL's